# Trying to write a jquerying script that uses a submit function to validate two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to meet the following objectives but having problems with my code to get it to work. Any help would be grateful.

Objective: Add javascript/jQuery code to require a login.  Have 2 fields, First Name  and Last Name.  Validate entry.   Must be "Rick" and "James" respectively. Once fields are validated, have a picture appear on the page.  When you click the picture, have the page content display.  Have at least 2 link buttons with rollover states to change button color and/or text size.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#signup").validate({
      rules: {
        firstName: { required: true  },
        lastName:  { required: true  }
      }, //end rules
      messages:  {
         firstName: {required: "You must enter a value in this field."  },
         lastName: {required: "You must enter a value in this field."  }
      }, // end messages
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
          error.insertAfter(element);
          } 
     }); // end validate
     $('#signup').submit(function() {
         if (($('#firstname').val() == 'John')  && ($('#lastname').val() == 'Taylor'))
            {alert('This works!');
            $('#pic').show();
            $('#main').css("backgorund-image", "url(starwars.jpg)");
          }
         else { alert('Invalid Name'); }
      });  //end submit
    $('#pic').click(function() {
        $('#button1').show();
        $('#button2').show();
    }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

HTML:

```
<form id="signup">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName" class="label">First Name</label>
            <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstname"  class="required" title="Please type your first name.">
        </div>          
        <div>
            <label for="lastName" class="label">Last Name</label>
            <input name="lastName" type="test" class="required" id="lastname">
        </div>          
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src="sith_ewok.png" id="pic">
        <button id="button1">Jedi</button>
        <button id="button2">Sith</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: My answer below addresses the two issues that appear likely to cause undesired behavior. To go beyond that, you would need to specify exactly what is happening/going wrong in your code currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error that stands out so far in your code is spelling `background-image` incorrectly in the submit function.

The one thing that seems likely is that you would see minimal effects from clicking the submit button because of the form automatically posting. That will likely mean that you never see the effects of your script being executed. To fix that, add `return false;` to the submit processing:

```
   $('#signup').submit(function() {
     if (($('#firstname').val() == 'John')  && ($('#lastname').val() == 'Taylor'))
     {alert('This works!');
        $('#pic').show();
        $('#main').css("backgorund-image", "url(starwars.jpg)");
      }
     else { alert('Invalid Name'); }
     return false;
  });  //end submit
```

Note that if you are actually going to use this form to do further processing on another page, you might later want to have the submit function allow the page to post in the case that the fields check out. To do that, move the `return false;` line of code into the `else` and/or add a `return true;` as the last line in the main `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

Make up your mind! Is it  "Rick James" or  'John Taylor' ?!

Anyways, the code looks alright except

1. your should put `return false;` in `$.submit()` to prevent page
   refreshing
2. spelling errors on `background-color`
3. image and two buttons should be set to `display:none` at beginning, so the `show()` function will actually works

Also I do not see your code for changing button color/state anywhere. So I just added some `.mouseover` and `.mouseout` events on the buttons. This is normaly can be done with just css such as `button:hover {color:red}`.

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dUG8Y/

Hope it helps, and may the Force be with you.